# You might want to/need to consider

Tags: verbs

1. You **might want to** consider quitting your barista job.
2. You **might want to** spend more time studying and less time playing video games.

Q1): I know "you **might want to**..." means "I **suggest/recommend**...". Do we use "you **might need to**..." to mean the same thing too?

Q2): Can I use sentence (2), or rather "you **might want to**...", in a different context where the speaker is not sure whether "you" intend to do the thing mentioned, and therefore just guessing "**maybe** you want to do X or **maybe not**, I don't know"?

Answer (score 0):

1. I feel “you might need to...” suggests a much stronger recommendation, to a point where it almost suggests necessity.
   Example - You might need to come to the office again because I found some discrepancies in your form.
2. No. Maybe and maybe not show uncertainties. “You might want to...” is a recommendation.
   Example - Your grades weren’t good enough, you might want to work on your math.
   The sentence doesn’t make much sense if you use “maybe”. Or whatever sense it does make, it’s similar to using the formerly mentioned one, so why use the latter?

Answer (score 0):

> You might want to consider quitting your barista job.

The use of 'want' is still keeping a place for the other person to think. This is synonymous to the following sentence:

> You might as well consider quitting your barista job.

On the other hand,

> You might need to consider quitting your barista job.

The above sentence shows an urgency regarding the situation of quitting the barista job. This is showing a stronger suggestion compared to the previous statements. This is fairly synonymous to:

> You should consider quitting your barista job.

---

There is no need of adding extra words to the sentence to depict that there are possibilities of something happening. When you are suggesting something to someone, it certainly is a possibility for that other person to choose from. 'Guessing they might take up the suggestion' is equivalent to 'a possibility coming true', and 'Guessing they might not' is equivalent to 'possibility turning false'.

> You might want to spend more time studying and less time playing video games.

This sentence itself is sufficient to convey that you can do as suggested or cannot. Hence, no need to add redundant phrases. You can use it in other situations depicting possibilities. You can rephrase it to mean the same thing,

> You might as well consider spending more time studying and less time playing video games.